# DynamoDb .AsyncSearch<T>.GetRemainingAsync hangs randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS .Net Core SDK to connect with Amazon DynamoDB, everything works fine except for repeatedly and randomly getting timeouts (around 30 seconds per request).

I used logging and traced the issue back to GetRemainingAsync method after getting scan operation results.

```
    public async Task<IList<T>> GetByPropertyAsync(List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> properties)
    {
        var conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            conditions.Add(new ScanCondition(property.Key, ScanOperator.Equal, property.Value));
        }
        var response = base.ScanAsync<T>(conditions, _config);
        return response.GetRemainingAsync().Result;
    }
```

When logging and sending multi requests (one by one) the line `response.GetRemainingAsync().Result` hangs around 30 seconds, this is happening frequently.

Might be a threading related issue, I tried to run this line in a seperate thread using:

```
Task.Run(() => response.GetRemainingAsync()).Result;
```

But that did not work either.

Comment: Is that really the code you're using? Why are you calling `.Result` since your `GetByPropertyAsync` method is async?

Comment: I don't want to paste more code, I have a part calling this method as sync.

Comment: @YahyaHussein Mixing async and blocking calls like `.Result` can lead to deadlocks. you need to use async-await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was down to `response.GetRemainingAsync()` getting `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` that will trigger retry till time out happens which sounds like a hang.

The solution is increasing the ProvisionedThroughput limit or switching to on demand model, or of course updating the retry policy dynamodb client follows.